# Can't get query string parameter value

Tags: php, wordpress, opayo

I have integrated sage pay with my wordpress site. I am currently running sagepay in simulator mode.

After successful payment sagepay redirects to the success page of my site. The redirect url is like this.

```
mysite.com/?page_id=632&crypt=@7564ASKJjkkjh....encrypted string.
```

when i am trying to get query string parameter on my success page by $_REQUEST or $_GET i can only get page_id.

But I can't get 'crypt' parameter.

I have also tried var_dump($_REQUEST). It also gives only page_id but not crypt parameter.

I wan't to retrieve  'crypt' parameter from query string.

**Note: Its working on localhost properly. I got both parameters. But when i uploaded my site on live server, i can get only page_id, but not 'crypt' parameter .**

Any Ideas?

Update:
my querystring given by Sage pay is like this:

mysite.com/?page_id=632&crypt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

but its works fine on localhost

Comment: Are you able to post the `crypt` parameter?

Comment: Just try without the @ sign and see if that works. That will atleast narrow down the issue :-)

Comment: Nope. This redirection is done by Sage Pay system after successful payment. So we can't set mehod type.

Comment: @PrakashPala can you `urlencode` the parameters? or do you have no control over them?

Comment: To Ben Carley:crypt parameter is sent by Sage Pay . We can't alter its value :(

Comment: Yes, we have no control over this string.

Comment: @PrakashPala Ah, this is very weird. Would you mind updating your question with the full request? Just to check there are no other problems :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19516/discussion-between-prakash-pala-and-ben-carey)

Comment: @PrakashPala Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

It seems that you are running the Suhosin Security Patch. This patch limits your `$_GET` parameter to a maximum of 512 bytes.

In order to get around this, you will need to add a value to your `php.ini`.

```
suhosin.get.max_value_length = LIMIT_HERE
```

### Reference

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469

> Please note that PHP setups with the suhosin patch installed will have
>   a default limit of 512 characters for get parameters. Although bad
>   practice, most browsers (including IE) supports URLs up to around 2000
>   characters, while Apache has a default of 8000.
>
> To add support for long parameters with suhosin, add
>   `suhosin.get.max_value_length = <limit>` in php.ini

**UPDATE 1**

As you do not have access to your `php.ini`, you will need to change the value in either an `.htacess` file (if you are using Apache), or alternatively, you may be able to do it using the built in PHP function `ini_set()`.

.htacess method:

```
php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 8000
```

ini_set method:

```
ini_set('suhosin.get.max_value_length', '8000');
```

**However, it is likely *(but not certain)* that your PHP installation will not allow modification of the Suhosin variables on a per directory basis. In order to fix this, you must request this to be placed into your `php.ini`, otherwise there is nothing you can do.**

```
suhosin.perdir = "p"
```

Comment: Ya but I can't access php.ini file on server. Is there any way to upload custom php.ini or make some changes in .htaccess file for particular this fix?
and +1 for your help :)

Comment: @PrakashPala You cannot upload a custom php.ini in most cases. The best thing to do would be to use an `htaccess` file or `ini_set()`. Will amend answer

Comment: Thanks Ben! Issue is solved. I have uploaded my custom php.ini file with suhosin.get.max_value_length = 6000. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think your production environment have configured filters in php.ini for $_REQUEST, check the filter section of your php.ini, more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.configuration.php

If you don't want to change this configuration on your production environment, you can access the value using filter_input, more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php